# Applying a metabox option to current page and all child pages

Tags: wordpress, parent-child, meta-boxes

This is a bit of a head scratcher, I'm not sure how to go about this or even if this would be the best method.

However this is my scenario:

I need to apply a specific colour to a wordpress page. I was planning to create a metabox where the user is allowed to select one of 5 colours. Now this is where it gets a bit tricky, I want this colour selection to apply to all child pages as well.

Is there a way to check if a parent page has a specific metabox option selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with some fairly standard logic:

- check to see if the post_meta value is set
- check if this is a child, get the parent id, check if a post_meta value is set

Here's some code to show how this could work (within the loop):

```
if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'colour', TRUE) ) {
    $colour = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'colour', TRUE);
} elseif ( $post->post_parent && get_post_meta($post->post_parent, 'colour', TRUE) ) {
    $colour = get_post_meta($post->post_parent, 'colour', TRUE);
} else {
    $colour = '#fff'; // could put a default value here
}
//do something with $colour variable
```

And when you're outside the loop you can use `get_queried_object()` to access the post object. IE:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();

if ( get_post_meta($queried_object->ID, 'colour', TRUE) ) {
    $colour = get_post_meta($queried_object->ID, 'colour', TRUE);
} elseif ( $queried_object->post_parent && get_post_meta($queried_object->post_parent, 'colour', TRUE) ) {
    $colour = get_post_meta($queried_object->post_parent, 'colour', TRUE);
} else {
    $colour = '#fff'; // could put a default value here
}
//do something with $colour variable
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this doesn't seem to be working on child pages. I am cheating a bit with the meta boxes by using advanced custom fields but from what I can see I have essentially the same code. Just exchanging the standard meta call with get_field('page_category', $post->ID)

Comment: @GRS The code would've only worked in the loop because you need access to the post object. I've just updated my answer to include an example using `get_queried_object()` which will let you use it outside the loop. Should be fine with ACF template tags.

Comment: Ahh I feel like a dope. Thanks for making things simple for me.